# Ubuntu for Android

Tags: linux

Is this actually downloadable in Google Play or elsewhere or is it just a project for willing OEMs?

Did anyone here use it?

http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android

Comment: @krsteeve You're talking about Ubuntu Touch. Mr. Brehm is asking about "Ubuntu for Android", which is listed as a separate project on the site he links to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's only for OEMs at this point. The developers did a Q&A on Reddit a few months back where they basically stated they had no immediate plans to release UfA (see, e.g., [this comment thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1jqfce/we_are_the_engineering_team_behind_ubuntu_for/cbhbq9j)). Don't know if anything has changed since, but the lack of a "download" button would imply it has not.